# modified Form FOSUserbundle

Tags: symfony, token, csrf, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserbundle and want to modify the ugly standard forms with the override method.

Currently I got problems with the csrf token.
"The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."

I have tried to generate the token with the following:

```
csrf_token("authenticate") and csrf_token('intention') throw this error.
```

```
<label for="fos_user_profile_form_current_password" class="required">
<input type="text" id="fos_user_profile_form_username" name="fos_user_profile_form[username]" required="required" maxlength="255" pattern=".{2,}" value="kristof" />
 <input type="email" id="fos_user_profile_form_email" name="fos_user_profile_form[email]" required="required" value="kristof@example.de" />

 <input type="password" id="fos_user_profile_form_current_password" name="fos_user_profile_form[current_password]" required="required" />
 <input type="text" id="fos_user_profile_form__token" name="fos_user_profile_form[_token]" value="{{ csrf_token }}"  />

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="profile.edit.submit" />
</div>
```

How do i implement the csrf to my custom form?

In my security.yml you can read this:

```
provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

Comment: What form you are overriding? the `csrf_token` is generated from a form or from a controller with a `tokenId`.

Comment: Btw, the `input` token must be `hidden`

Comment: I just made it as text to see the value but thanks.

Comment: {{ tokenId }} didn't worked for me: {Neither the property "tokenId" nor one of the methods "tokenId()", "gettokenId()"/"istokenId()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\user" in FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig at line 17}

Comment: the valid token id in your case should be `'profile'` see my answer for the solution.